# Extracting Month Date Wordpress

Tags: php, date, format

Bonjour,

I'm trying te extract month from a custom field date in wordpress.
My problem is while `$eventDate = 24/**12**/2019`, the instruction `echo date('M', $eventDate)` prints "JAN" instead of "**DEC**".

Here's the code:

```php
<?php 
$eventDate = strtotime(get_field('event_date'));
echo date('M', $eventDate);
?>
```

Merci

Answer (score 1):

`strtotime` cannot process with 'd/m/Y' format, and it's output is `false`, then `date('M', false)` will output `"jan"`

Use `$eventDate = date_create_from_format("d/m/Y",'24/12/2019');` instead.